# perf-events not showing StackTraces on debian 8 jessie

Tags: profiling, stack-trace, debug-symbols, perf, debian-jessie

I am trying to profile a simple C program with perf-events on debian 8 jessie. I can see symbols but I am unable to get stacktraces. The same procedure generates good stacktraces on ubuntu 16.04.

I have installed `linux-image-amd64-dbg` and `libc6-dbg`.
I have confirmed that kernel config parameters include `CONFIG_KALLSYMS=y`

I have compiled the program with `gcc -g3 -O0 hello.c` to enable debug symbols.

I start profiling with the following command. 
`sudo perf record -g ./a.out`

I generate a flame graph [Flame Graph](http://www.brendangregg.com/flamegraphs.html) with the following command

```
sudo perf script | ~/code/FlameGraph/stackcollapse-perf.pl | \
~/code/FlameGraph/flamegraph.pl > perf-kernel.svg
```

This is the listing for hello.c which I am trying to profile

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


void do2() {
    FILE* f = fopen("/dev/zero", "r");
    int fd = fileno(f);
    char buf[100];
    while(1) {
        read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)/sizeof(buf[0]));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    do2();
    return 0;
}
```

[This is the flame graph with debian jessie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAylR.png)

[This is the flame graph with ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7K9m.png)

Why are stack traces missing in debian jessie?

Thanks
Sharath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the issue.
I had to enable `CONFIG_FRAME_POINTER=y` and recompile the kernel as per [Brendan Gregg's perf site](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html#StackTraces)

It is unfortunate that the kernel shipping with Debian 8 does not have this enabled, which breaks perf